# How to hide navigation bar on home screen of Samsung J6

Tags: navigation-bar

How to hide the navigation bar on home screen of Samsung J6?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe that in the Settings app, you could setup the full screen mode setting especially for the default samsung launcher.
By this way you could hide the navigation bar, or the statubar or the navigation bar and the statubar.